# Julia: what does the "<:" symbol mean?

Tags: julia

What does this mean in function signatures, for example:

`convert(::Type{T}, z::Complex) where {T<:Real}`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Strictly speaking, one should differentiate between the predicate `Base.:(<:)`, as described in @Saqib's answer, and the syntactic usage of `<:` for describing constraints.

This syntactic usage can occur in type parameter declarations of methods, to constrain a type variable to be a subtype of some other type:

```
f(x::T) where {T<:Real} = zero(x)
```

A sort of special case of this is when you constrain the type parameter of a struct (`struct Foo{T<:Real} ... end`) -- that constrains the methods of the generated constructor, and allows the type constructor to be applied only to the constrained subtypes.

On the other hand, outside of type parameters, `<:` can be used to declare a new type as a subtype of some other (necessarily abstract) type:

```
struct Foo <: Real end
```

Although both cases are in line with the meaning of the subtyping predicate, you can't replace them with other arbitrary expressions (e.g., you can't write `... where {isreal(T)}` in `f`).

Comment: Actually, if I type `struct Foo{T<:Real} end; Foo{String}` into the REPL, I get `TypeError: in Foo, in T, expected T<:Real, got Type{String}`, which indicates to me that it's not just a constraint on the constructors (on Julia version 1.5). Maybe `Foo{String}` used to work, but now they've fixed that behavior?

Comment: See my comment on the other question, I had a wrong believe and messed up my test case.

Comment: Although it still is a special case, somehow. I guess we could think of the semantics as defining a method `Core.apply_type(::Type{Foo}, ::Type{T}) where {T<:Real})` (if that were not a built-in).

Answer (score 7):

**<:(T1, T2)**

Subtype operator: returns `true` if and only if all values of type `T1` are
also of type `T2`.

**Examples:**

```
Float64 <: AbstractFloat
=> true

Vector{Int} <: AbstractArray
=> true

Matrix{Float64} <: Matrix{AbstractFloat}
=> false
```

Comment: Note this is just the docstring for `<:` accessible in the Julia REPL by entering `?<:`.