# Julia Matrix{AbstractFloat} type question

Tags: julia

## Context

In [Julia: what does the "<:" symbol mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53015450/3184351), the 2nd answer directly quoted the three [Julia's documentation for the `<:` operator](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#Core.:%3C:).  The 3rd one puzzles me.

## Problem

To make this question independent from the quoted question, I'll make a particular example.

```
julia> 1.3 isa AbstractFloat
true
julia> [1.3 1.3; 1.2 1.2] isa Matrix{Float64}
true
julia> [1.3 1.3; 1.2 1.2] isa Matrix{AbstractFloat}
false
```

From Julia's documentation, `AbstractFloat` is an abstract type for all floating values, e.g. `Float32`, `Float64`, etc.  That's explains the first example.  However, I can't understand why a matrix of `Float64` isn't a matrix of `AbstractFloat`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do:

```
julia> [1.3 1.3; 1.2 1.2] isa Matrix{<:AbstractFloat}
true
```

as type parameters in Julia are *invariant*.

This is explained in detail [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/types/#man-parametric-composite-types).

If the linked explanation is not clear please comment where you need additional info and I can expand on the problematic areas.

#### EDIT

An explanation from a different angle (maybe it will be also helpful).

1. As is explained [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/types/#man-types) in Julia:

> One particularly distinctive feature of Julia's type system is that concrete types may not subtype each other: all concrete types are final and may only have abstract types as their supertypes. While this might at first seem unduly restrictive, it has many beneficial consequences with surprisingly few drawbacks.

The reason for this is that concrete types have a concrete memory layout, and in particular `Matrix{Float64}` and `Matrix{AbstactFloat}` have a different memory layout. Knowing memory layout of an object is crucial if we want the compiler to emit efficient machine code.

2. Now both `Matrix{AbstractFloat}` and `Matrix{Float64}` are concrete types (they can have instances):

```
julia> Matrix{AbstractFloat}(undef,0,0)
0×0 Matrix{AbstractFloat}

julia> Matrix{Float64}(undef,0,0)
0×0 Matrix{Float64}

julia> isconcretetype(Matrix{AbstractFloat})
true

julia> isconcretetype(Matrix{Float64})
true
```

3. In consequence `Matrix{Float64}` cannot be a subtype of `Matrix{AbstractFloat}` (nor vice versa)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but honestly I find its explanation too technical for beginners to understand.  I find [Wiki's explanation about invariance of arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_%28computer_science%29#Arrays) much easier to understand: if `Cat[]` was treated as `Animals[]`, to which we could add put `Dog`, we would be putting a `Dog` into a `Cat[]`.  I suppose the `struct Point{T}` in Julia's docs as a mutable data type, so for the sake of type safety, the tyep param `T` has to be invar.

Comment: I have added an additional Julia-specific explanation. I hope this helps.